# Are there realistic applications to predictive analysis of complex systems now handled by AI?

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I use HPC hardware and AI software to forecast stock market prices in real time. My system is running into hardware and operating system limitations so I am wondering if it would be productive to experiment with a quantum computer. If anyone has any experience or expertise using a quantum computer for finance, please share your ideas and expertise. Thanks. Daro

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that under current state of development, quantum computers cannot be massively deployed in finance industry. However, the area is developing rapidly.

You can find some overview of possible quantum computers application in finance here: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2405428318300571

Comment: I think I can create the algorithms; my current work is very close already. What eludes me is how to get timely access to the hardware at a reasonable price,

Comment: Try IBM Q Experience. You can use a quantum computer as a cloud service for free for testing. For commercial use, you would have to pay, I think.

Comment: @DaroGross It's hard to gage your level of familiarity with QIT, but "I think I can create the algorithms" is a bold statement.  If you haven't done so already, you should get familiar with key existing algorithms, for example Shor's algorithm and/or Grover's algorithm, to get a sense of the how dramatically quantum algorithms differ from classical algorithms.

Comment: I am doing HPC with algorithms that look like quantum computing algorithms. I just cannot afford real time access to a quantum computer so I use AI techniques to simulate the parallelism of quantum computing on a server with many CPUs. However, I am very interested in learning about the work of others that would help me to create better quantum computing algorithms. There is no reason to reinvent the wheel, and this is a world of clever tricks.

Comment: @DaroGross: " to simulate the parallelism of quantum computing". Please correct me anybody if I am wrong but quantum computer does not provide parallelism, it is one of widespread misconception based on idea that thank to superposition we are able to make $2^n$ calculation simultaneously on $n$ qubits register. But this is not the case.   Regarding the affordability of real quantum hardware, as I mentioned in my earlier comment, you can create account at IBM Q Experience website for free and experiment with your quantum algorithms. Here is a link: https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/

Comment: Perhaps my terminology is not clear. In the initial pass, the cubits hold all possible states. When measured, they collapse into into statistical randomness that can be amplified to extract output values. This is massive parallelism in a serial pipeline. All I need to do is filter the data into compressed representations of the desired outputs, like I do with AI. Please correct me if I am not seeing something clearly. Thanks.